# CORS in Prolog not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, prolog, cors, swi-prolog

I have a problem on cors in prolog. I think it not working.

Edit #1

```
:- module(server,[]).

:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_cors)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).
:- use_module(library(http/json_convert)).
:- use_module(library(option)).
:- use_module(library(settings)).
:- http_handler(root(.),handle,[]).

:- set_setting(http:cors, [*]).
server(Port) :-
   http_server(http_dispatch,[port(Port)]).

:- json_object
        poke(pokemon:text, move:text).
handle(Request) :-
   format(user_output,"Request is: ~p~n",[Request]),
   format(user_output,"Request2 is: ~p~n",[]),
   cors_enable,
   http_read_json_dict(Request, DictIn,[json_object(term)]),
   format(user_output,"I'm here~n",[]),
   term_string(Pokemon,DictIn.pokemon),
   findall(poke(P,M),beat(P,M,Pokemon),L),
   prolog_to_json(L,J),
   format(user_output,"Pokemons are: ~p~n",[J]),
   DictOut=J,
   reply_json(DictOut).

beat(P,M,E) :-
   pokerule:beat(P,M,E).
```

However I use ajax post to prolog server it said

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9999/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Ajax that I use to post.

```
   let enemyName = this.item.text
   let data = {"pokemon":enemyName}
   $.ajax({
     url        : END_POINT,
     method     : 'post',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType   : 'json',
     data       : JSON.stringify(data),
     success    : function (res) {
       console.log(res);
     },
     error :function (res) {
       console.log(res);
     } 
   })
```

How can I solve this problem?

-Edited
Now I fix some of my code but it still not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [**documentation**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpcors) of `library(http/http_cors)`:

> Because CORS is a security risc (see references), it is disabled by default. **It is enabled through the setting http:cors. The value of this setting is a list of domains that are allowed to access the service. Because * is used as a wildcard match, the value [*] allows access from anywhere.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Thus, in your server, you probably must include the setting:

```
:- set_setting(http:cors, [*]).
```

By default, *nothing* is written by `cors_enable/0`.

Next time, please construct a minimal example that others can actually *try out*.

**EDIT**: Your edited code has elementary problems that have *nothing to do* with CORS. Please reduce this to a *minimal* example. You can see what is wrong by:

1. Starting the server with `?- server(4050).` (for example)
2. Visiting, in your web browser, `http://localhost:4050`.

You will see error messages that indicate problems.

Here is a small skeleton for `handle/2` that you can extend as necessary:

```
handle(Request) :-
        cors_enable,
        reply_json(test{x: 1, y: 2}).
```

Comment: I add that line to my code. However it still not working.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note that several unrelated problems overshadow your actual question. Next time, please make the example as short as possible.

Comment: Note that prolog docs lack that setting you mentions in your answer. Next time, please don't share your knowledge out of the blue, and contribute to the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

I could somehow identify the problem, which is due to the request header sent from the browser. It sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` to the prolog server, which makes the server to fail at `is_json_type(String)` in `http_json.pl`. Quick fix is to insert the following lines to the predicate:

`is_json_type(String)` :-

```
String = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', !.
```

You had also better remove the following line of the javascript:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

because it is not also recognized by the server. I recommend only to use tags, type, dataType, url, and data within javascript to hand those parameters to the server.

I found it difficult to predict what the request of the browser contains because it depends on browsers. I thus believe that it would be hard work to maintain the prolog program up to date, considering every possible items of information sent from browsers. You had better check what items are included in the request when the server fails to finish the task.